# Как посчитать разницу во времени (JS)?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Добрый день, мне приходят данные в string формате: '11:43' и '13:14'
Помогите правильно написать скрипт что-бы высчитывал разницу между этими двумя числами, должно получиться 01:31.
Можно через Moment JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно вам будет достаточно такого решения:

```js
let firstDate = '11:43';
let secondDate = '13:14';
   
let getDate = (string) => new Date(0, 0,0, string.split(':')[0], string.split(':')[1]); //получение даты из строки (подставляются часы и минуты
let different = (getDate(secondDate) - getDate(firstDate));

let hours = Math.floor((different % 86400000) / 3600000);
let minutes = Math.round(((different % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
let result = hours + ':' + minutes;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, отличное решение!

Comment: Не надо из времени дату делать. Часовые пояса и всякая другая ерунда могут попортить результат.

Comment: @Qwertiy А разве часовой пояс (и всякая другая) не присвоится к обеим строкам и разница между датами не поменяется. Или если я что-то путаю, то буду рад услышать от Вас более конкретный пример, который нарушит данную логику, чтобы исправить свое решение и заодно получить новые знания.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, что если между получившимися датами окажется переход на летнее время, например? Или какой-нибудь диапазон пропущенных дат? Или смена часового пояса? https://habrahabr.ru/post/146109/

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо за довольно исчерпывающую информацию. А теперь немного разбора. Переход на летнее время осуществляется в полночь, а это уже получается выход за пределы одних суток и сравнивать часы и минуты - недостаточно. Если имеются только часы и минуты, то new Date() подставит текущий часовой пояс, который не будет влиять на результат. А если есть пропущенные даты, то тогда, скорее всего нужно больше данных для решения данной задачи, так как опять же идет выход за пределы одних суток, а формат данных подразумевает только часы и минуты.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, не в полночь, а в 02:00 или 03:00. По крайней мере так было, пока его не отменили.

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо за уточнение, не задавался раньше вопросом о времени перевода. Но, замечу, что Вы сами подметили, что его отменили, что делает этот фактор не играющим никакой роли в данной проблеме. Ну или это должно, оговориться в начальных требованиях при постановке проблемы.

Comment: Во-первых, его только в России отменили, в США по-прежнему есть, например. Во-вторых, тут недавно часовой пояс меняли. А где-то сменили часовой пояс на 24 часа и выкинули 31 декабря просто. Моё мнение, что лучше не связываться с датами, если они тебе явно не нужны.

Answer (score 5):

Можно поступить так:

1. распарсить отдельно первое и второе значение string на часы и минуты
2. часы умножить на 60 и сложить с минутами и получится одно число в минутах
3. должно получиться 11*60+43=703 и 13*60+14=794
4. вычесть из первых минут вторые и ответ взять по модулю
5. получится |703-794|=91
6. дальше просто ответ делим на 60 и получаем количество часов, т.е. 1
7. и в конце вычитаем из ответа количество часов *60, т.е. 91-60*1=31 и получаем минуты

Итого 1 час 31 минута

Comment: Только вычесть из вторых первые и никакой модуль не нужен.

Comment: А если второе значение меньше первого? Метод с модулем универсален.

Comment: Нет, метод с модулем спорный. Во-первых, в вопросе ничего не говорится о том, что второе время может быть меньше. Во-вторых, если какое-то событие началось в 23:55 и закончилось в 00:05, то правильная длительность 00:10, а модуль даст 23:50. Чаще к отрицательному результату надо будет сутки добавлять, чем обрабатывать, что значения могут быть в неверном порядке переданы.

Comment: "если какое-то событие началось в 23:55 и закончилось в 00:05" то важно какого числа началось и какого закончилось. В вопросе сказано "высчитывал разницу между этими двумя числами". Если речь идёт о датах то только товарищ [Puvvl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/222191/puvvl) сможет нас рассудить.

Answer (score 1):

Немного дописал скрипт, если время началось в 23:43 и закончилось в 04:14 выдаст правильный ответ.

```js
let firstDate = '23:43';
let secondDate = '04:14';
let getDate = (string) => new Date(0, 0,0, string.split(':')[0], string.split(':')[1]);
let different = (getDate(secondDate) - getDate(firstDate));
let differentRes, hours, minuts;
if(different > 0) {
  differentRes = different;
  hours = Math.floor((differentRes % 86400000) / 3600000);
  minuts = Math.round(((differentRes % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
} else {
  differentRes = Math.abs((getDate(firstDate) - getDate(secondDate)));
  hours = Math.floor(24 - (differentRes % 86400000) / 3600000);
  minuts = Math.round(60 - ((differentRes % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000);
}
let result = hours + ':' + minuts;
console.log(result)
```